# Saving ArrayList of Parcelable objects as persistent data?

Tags: android

I have an ArrayList of custom Parcelable objects and I'm trying to save this list to external/internal data storage. These objects are called Lectures and each Lecture contains Arraylists of Assignments, Tests, Notes, and Settings. All of these implement Parcelable too.

Now I attempted to save to this to the sd card using:

```
for(Lecture l : lectureList)
    oos.writeObject(l);
```

oos being the ObjectOutputStream. An exception is thrown (InvalidDataException? I don't remember) with the first write. Now I thought Parcelable was Android's own implementation of Serializable - but upon further reading it seems Parcelable might not be route to save objects persistently. Which is an issue becuase I use it for saveInstanceState.

So do I

- implement Serializable with Parcelable or remove Parcelable first?
- save my data to storage with a different method?
- or call it a good run and wave the white flag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anybody cares... I ended up implementing Serializable with Parcelable and it works just fine for both persistent and restoring the state of my app.